# Crystal Reports - Total Page Count exported to text file incorrectly - produces additional characters

Tags: crystal-reports

I have "Total Page Count" field in Page Header section of my report and single column of data in Details sections (its header in Page Header).

When I export this to text file strange staff happens:

1) When field is wide enough it produces following line:

> 15    1

Where 15 looks to be actual page count (base on number of "lines per page"), but have no clue what is "1"

2) When field is narrower to fit this. Only "1" is displayed, but "15" mess one of following lines (here header of data column):

> ```
>                          1
>    C15tID
>    100 004 596,00
>    100 004 603,00
> ```

[Total Page Count invalid location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55I8f.png)

How can I make this display proper page count or at least make sure characters do not overwrite other lines?

Comment: Where did you place the rest of lines in design of report?

Comment: @Siva: There is single column of data in details section and it's header in page header section (question updated).

Comment: Can you check if there is option checked `underlay following sections` for page header...if yes then un check that option and check report

Comment: No, this this option is not checked.

Comment: Can you show formula and design

Comment: It happens to any report, even so simple as this one:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26030846/TotalPageCount%20problem.rpt
BTW: I'm using CR designer 2016, but it also happen in 2013.

Comment: unable to open the link.. can you check link

Comment: Try different location:
https://valthorens.blob.core.windows.net/rpt/TotalPageCount%20problem.rpt